# roster.getPresence gives unavailable

Tags: java, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

I am using smack api.

```
        Presence presencePacket = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
        presencePacket.setTo("dhmohn@example.com");
        conn1.sendPacket(presencePacket);

        Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
        Roster roster=conn1.getRoster();

        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();

        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
            System.out.println(roster.getPresence(entry.getUser()));
        }
```

In the above code `roster.getPresence(entry.getUser())` gives status as `unavailable`

In addition, I have following queries:

1. Here `dhmohn@example.com` is email id of the user whose username is `danmorgan`. Am I using the correct **jid**?
2. If the above **jid** is wrong, then what could be the correct **jid**? Btw I have tried the following **jid** too: `danmorgan@saint-pc`.

Please take a note, that at **openfire server** i have **set subscription mode as both** for both the user.

Comment: What domain have you set on your server? Your JID should be username@domain.con

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JID** is an indispensable part.

Always use **JID** to login. The **JID** is combination of **username** and **server** **name**.
So, in my case the JID would be username@server-name i.e **dhmohn@saint-pc** as the **username** is **dhmohn** and **server name** is **saint-pc**.

Please take a note, if you login with the following code then your roster will always be empty:

```
conn1.login("dhmohn", "Dhmohn123");
```

Rather, always login with the jabber ID:

```
conn1.login("dhmohn@saint-pc", "Dhmohn123");
```

After logging in, put the thread to sleep for 10 seconds. Later fetch the roster.

One could find the **server name** in **admin console of Openfire**:

```
server tab ->server manager->server informaton->server properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                    connection.sendPacket(presence);

```
                Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                roster.addRosterListener(new RosterListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void presenceChanged(Presence presence) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String user = presence.getFrom();
                        // Presence bestPresence = roster.getPresence(user);
                        Log.e("User Presence--------->****-->",
                                "User Name-----" + user
                                        + "Online or Offline ---->"
                                        + presence.isAvailable());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void entriesUpdated(Collection<String> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void entriesDeleted(Collection<String> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void entriesAdded(Collection<String> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
```

Here You can get update of Presence Of User when he is going to Offline and online when Presence Changed.